# What does the composer.phar file do?

Tags: terminal, installation, composer-php, phpmailer

I use composer on a website, I already have it working, but i'm not totally aware of what the composer.phar file does. Is it a mannual installation or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer.phar` *is* composer. A [phar file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php) is a PHP app packaged into a single runnable script. If your composer commands are already working, you've already got it, and you don't need to install anything else.

Note that you don't necessarily need composer installed on your server at all; generate your vendor folder locally and upload it - from that point it's just a folder full of scripts, `autoload.php` in particular.